# What's wrong with my SQL code? Getting an error on line 9

Tags: sql

I'm trying to import the code below into a MySQL database. However it says that I have an error on line 9 involving the ')' token. Any idea how to fix it? Error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 9
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

```
CREATE TABLE user_types (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    description VARCHAR(255),
    rank INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(64),
    email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ip_address VARCHAR(255),
    user_agent VARCHAR(255),
    type INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    first_name VARCHAR(64),
    last_name VARCHAR(64),
    biography TEXT,
    dob_month INT UNSIGNED,
    dob_year INT UNSIGNED,
    dob_day INT UNSIGNED,
    interests VARCHAR(255),
    gender VARCHAR(64),
    created INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sessions (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ip_address VARCHAR(255),
    user_agent VARCHAR(255),
    created INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    last_activity INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: try running the queries one at a time; otherwise, you don't know which "line 9" it is referring.

Comment: remove the comma before `)`

Comment: Simple typos (extra `,` before `);`) in several places.

Comment: Yep seems like that was the problem. Removing the commas fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several `CREATE TABLE` statements have a trailing comma after the last column, which should be removed.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE announcements (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    content TEXT,
    labels VARCHAR(255),
    created INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    archived INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);
```

Should be:

```
CREATE TABLE announcements (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    content TEXT,
    labels VARCHAR(255),
    created INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    archived INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

With these changes the schema is building successfully on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cde4).